# amazon s3 upload from react : forbidden

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I use S3FileUpload from react-s3 to upload

```
const config = {
  bucketName: "bucketName",
  dirName: "dirName",
  region: "eu-west-3",
  accessKeyId: KeyId,
  secretAccesKey: secretKey,
};
```

I use keyId and secretKey to upload file from my react application. But I have an error 403 Forbidden.

My CORS configuration is OK and my bucket is public.

Comment: @ccoenjeux: Please provide more information here about the problem you are facing. For example, It would be also helpful if you post your config files as well.

Comment: @connect2coder Hi, my config file is just where I declare my KeyId and my secretAccesKey.

Comment: What do you mean by "my bucket is public"? Can you show us the Bucket Policy, and also the permissions associated with the Access Key that the code is using?

Comment: Hi, I just put my access control list in Public. I havn't got bucket policy. Should I add json configuration to declare my access key ?

Comment: Can you provide the policy that is assigned for the role that is linked to the user? This sounds like a policy problem @cocoenjeux

Comment: I havnt got policy assigned for the role. So I think it's the problem